Math for ML Book (Exercise 5.9) Vector Calculus
We define
$$ 
g(z,v) := \log(p(x,z)) - \log(q(z,v)) 
$$
$$
z := t(e, v)
$$
for differentiable functions $p, q,t$. Compute gradient $\frac{d}{dv}g(z,v)$.
Attempt:
$$
\frac{dg}{dv} = \frac{dg}{dz} \frac{dz}{dv} + \frac{dg}{dv} \frac{dv}{dv} 
$$
implies
$$
\frac{dg}{dv} = \frac{dg}{dz} \frac{dz}{dv} + \frac{dg}{dv}
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{dg}{dz} = \frac{1}{p(x,z)} \frac{dp(x,z)}{dz} - \frac{1}{q(z,v)} \frac{dq(z,v)}{dz}
$$
$$
\frac{dz}{dv} = \frac{dt(e, v)}{dv} 
$$
$$
\frac{dg}{dv} = \frac{-1}{q(z,v)}\frac{dq(z,v)}{dv}
$$
Questions:
Plugging in the above to the chain rule equation defined above, is this correct?

Looks correct so far, but I guess you still have to compute the derivative of $t$ wrt $v$

The intermediate expression $dg/dv=(dg/dz)(dz/dv)+dg/dv$ doesn't make a lot of sense on its face, since it would require $(dg/dz)(dz/dv)=0$.

Try to use partial derivatives, the way you wrote the chain rule for $g$ does not make any sense.

Assuming ${e,x}$ are held constant, the gradient is
$$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\grad gv
:=: \frac1p\gradLR pz\gradLR zv
:-: \frac1q\gradLR qz\gradLR zv
:-: \frac1q\gradLR qv
$$

@HyperbolicPDEfriend i'm not sure how i would compute the derivative of t wrt v. they dont provide a definition for t.

@greg i believe what you have is what i have written above (assuming i wrote $dz/dv$ properly), but yours is simplified. However, it seems that semiclassical and ted black disagree with the way that i wrote the chain rule. Though I am not sure if they are saying that because I used the wrong notation for the partial derivative $(\frac{dq}{dz}$ vs $ \frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{z}} $
